# Testing for active flags during keyboard input

Tags: c++, keyboard-events, sdl-2

I am using SDL2 to poll events and forward the keyboard presses to a game object.  I pass in the `SDL_KeyBoardEvent` variable from a `SDL_KEYDOWN` event type.  I can't seem to understand how to manage the cases having modifier keys held down during input.

I compare MODK_Keys enums and the key.keysym.mod value of the SDL_KeyBoardEvent and it seems like it shouldn't enter the top if loop, but it does.  If I hold only `shift` and press any key like `a`, the output is the unexpected output in the first if statement.  It shows

```
1 0
Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 97
```

This `( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL ) )` is equal to zero during output, but is making it through the logical expression?  Below is the if statements

```
void KeyDown(SDL_KeyboardEvent key) {

    if( !( key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LSHIFT || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RSHIFT || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LCTRL || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RCTRL || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LALT || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RALT )) {

        if( ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT | KMOD_RSHIFT ) > 0 ) && ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL ) > 0 ) && ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT )  > 0  )) {
            std::cout << ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT | KMOD_RSHIFT ) ) << " " << ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL ) ) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Ctrl + Alt + Shift + " << key.keysym.sym  << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT |  KMOD_RSHIFT ) > 0 ) && ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL ) > 0 )) {
            std::cout << "Shift + Ctrl + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT |  KMOD_RSHIFT ) > 0 ) && ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT )  > 0 )) {
            std::cout << "Shift + Alt + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL ) > 0 ) && ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT )  > 0 )) {
            std::cout << "Ctrl + Alt + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT |  KMOD_RSHIFT ) > 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Shift + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT ) > 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Alt + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL ) > 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Ctrl + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Unmodded " << key.keysym.sym << " MODS: " << key.keysym.mod << std::endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slept on it and tried one thing different.  There is an error with my order of operations apparently.

Making the following switch worked (changed on all expressions)

`( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT | KMOD_RSHIFT ) > 0 )`

`(( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT | KMOD_RSHIFT )) > 0 )`

The function that works is

```
void KeyDown(SDL_KeyboardEvent key) {

    if( !( key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LSHIFT || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RSHIFT || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LCTRL || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RCTRL || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LALT || key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RALT )) {

        if( (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT | KMOD_RSHIFT )) > 0 ) && (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL )) > 0 ) && (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT ))  > 0  )) {
            std::cout << "Ctrl + Alt + Shift + " << key.keysym.sym  << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT |  KMOD_RSHIFT )) > 0 ) && (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL )) > 0 )) {
            std::cout << "Shift + Ctrl + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT |  KMOD_RSHIFT )) > 0 ) && (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT ))  > 0 )) {
            std::cout << "Shift + Alt + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL )) > 0 ) && (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT ))  > 0 )) {
            std::cout << "Ctrl + Alt + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LSHIFT |  KMOD_RSHIFT )) > 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Shift + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LALT | KMOD_RALT )) > 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Alt + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else if (( key.keysym.mod & ( KMOD_LCTRL | KMOD_RCTRL )) > 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Ctrl + " << key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Unmodded " << key.keysym.sym << " MODS: " << key.keysym.mod << std::endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: the ">0" is not necessary as everything >0 is evaluated as true. You can simply mask the mod with the OR  of KMOD_<wanted> like so: ```if (key.keysym.mod & (KMOD_LCTRL|KMOD_RCTRL)) {```